# Virtual Photon in Electron Scattering Feynman diagram

Tags: energy-conservation, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, virtual-particles

If we know that the virtual photon emitted in an electron scattering Feynman diagram violates the energy and momentum conservation laws (though temporarily), why do we accept it as a feasible diagram representing another perspective of reality?

Comment: Related/possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143038/50583, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/168845/50583, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55860/50583

Answer (score 5):

Internal lines are not *particles*: they are contractions of interacting fields (in the Dyson-Wick sense). We call them *virtual particles* to make it easy and efficient to communicate with each other, but they are **not** to be thought of as particles in no sense whatsoever. For example, the momentum carried by an internal line is just a Fourier variable, not the eigenvalue of the momentum operator (in this sense, we could write $\xi$ instead of $p$ for internal lines), and therefore it is not to be thought of as a physical momentum.

See [this other answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/253540/why-are-there-e-m-vacu%C3%BCm-fluctuations/253548#253548) if you want some more details.