# Using $\psi(t)=U(t)\psi(0)$ to derive, not the Schrodinger, but the relativistic QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, wavefunction

I am looking at the following derivation of the Schrodinger equation: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schrödinger_equation#Derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation#Derivation) which clearly shows how the Schrodinger equation can be derived starting with $\psi(t)=U(t)\psi(0)$ and taking the Taylor expansion of $U(t)$.

Furthermore, at this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wightman_axioms#W0_(assumptions_of_relativistic_quantum_mechanics) it states

> One basic idea of the Wightman axioms is that there is a Hilbert space
> upon which the Poincaré group acts unitarily

My question, is can we get either QFT or RQM by taking

$$
\psi(t)=U(t)\psi(0)
$$

where $U(t)$ is not a general unitary operator, but the unitary representation of the Poincaré group?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/257787/84967

Comment: Chapter 2 of Weinberg's book *The Quantum Theory of Fields* takes this approach to QFT.