# Unitarity of time-evolution operator of Dirac's equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, dirac-equation, pair-production

Let $\Psi(t)$ be state of Dirac's electron in context of Dirac's equation and consider time-evolution operator
$$\Psi(t) = U(t)\Psi(0)$$
is or is not $U$ an unitary (preserving length) operator?
(note that we could not simply write $U(t)=e^{-itH}$ and say it is unitary. theorem is converse: if we know that operator in unitary we could represent it in this form. but arbitrary operators don't have this form.)

I mean use of non-free Dirac's equation and examine $\Psi(t)$ has constant length in time? And I really hope the answer be $U$ is "not" unitary. Because I almost sure that even non-second-quantized Dirac's equation must provide some evidence to probability of creation ar annihilation of Dirac's particle.

Comment: re-write the Dirac equation in the form $i\frac{d}{dt} |\psi\rangle =H|\psi\rangle$, and verify if the $H$ you obtain is Hermitian. If yes, then $e^{-iHt}$ is unitary

Comment: see also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/257787/84967