# Information faster-than-light and GR vs. QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, faster-than-light, causality

1. What is meant by the statement that information cannot travel faster than light?
2. If I write down something on a paper, isn't there according to QM a non-zero probability that an identical paper can spontaneously fluctuate into existence a lightyear away?
3. Can't a person successfully guess every character that I write, every time?
4. Is this why QM and GR are incompatible?
5. If not, which principle or axiom of QM must be modified to be compatible with GR?
6. Is there any difference between ordinary particle travel and particles fluctuating in and out of existence along what looks like the world-line of a particle?
7. Other than different probabilities?
8. Can a Ferrari spontaneously fluctuate into existence according to QM?
9. What happens then to Energy conservation?

Comment: You've got a lot of questions there... could you edit this post to trim it down to one question, or just a couple of very closely related ones?

Comment: For the GR vs. QM issue, see e.g. [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/387/2451) and [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35486/2451) Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) google it (this forum requires you to first do some research of your own on your questions)

2) no, that would violate Conservation of Mass (QM says *virtual* particles pop in and out of existence, which are not real particles)

3) yes, so what?

4) no

*5) this should be your main question*, I can elaborate on it later.

6) yes, because the "particles" fluctuating in and out of existence are not real (see (2))

7) see (2)

8) see (2)

9) it is preserved (for *actual* particles)

Comment: actually mass is not conserved. It is conservation of energy that would be violated .

Comment: mass is energy...

Comment: For physicists mass has a definite meaning, given by the four vector measure. Mass has units of energy but it is not a conserved quantity . No physicist talks of conservation of mass. If the energy existed then the hypothetical doubling would not violate anything.