# What is an example of a situation where Quantum Mechanics and Relativity do not work together?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, relativity

I've learned special relativity in school last semester, and this semester we began learning about Quantum Mechanics, and my teacher told us that there was a Relativistic Schrodinger equation.

I was under the impression that you couldn't use Quantum Mechanics and Relativity together, so why is it appropriate to have a Relativistic Schrodinger equation, and what is an example of a situation where QM and Relativity cannot be used together?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/387/2451 and links therein.

Comment: QM + Special Relativity go together very nicely. "Quantum fied theory" is the marriage of both theories. You're thinking of general relativity, where we don't know how to consistently incorporate curved space with normal particle physics.