# Resource for nonphysicists about QM/GR incompatibility

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, resource-recommendations, popular-science

I don't know how to explain the issues at hand in a way that nonphysicists are certain to understand. Can anyone point me to some resource (book, video, it doesn't really matter) that will help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A list of inconveniences between quantum mechanics and relativity?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/387/) and links therein.

Comment: I saw that, but I don't know how I can show it to people with no physics background whatsoever and have them understand it. I tend toward technical explanations I speak.

Comment: Hi cartomancer. Welcome to Phys.SE. Your question (v1) is _off topic_ in the sense that we only allow a limited number of book recommendation posts. I close it _as a duplicate,_ not because it necessarily is, but to guide viewers in the right direction.

Comment: @Qmechanic it confuses me that such questions are still getting closed. Do we not have a change in the book policy according to [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4697/2751) meta post? The OP clearly specifies that he is interested in resources that can be understood without prerequisites, namely by non-physicists.