# General relativity && quantum mechanics "incompatibillity"

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity

Now this may be utterly weird layman-physics-question, but anyways...

I have read recently following:

"The fundamental universe laws are everywhere the same. It's just that the manifestation (!) of (these) laws is different (!) on a specific "scale"."

Which brings me to the question:

Could it be that GR and QM are one and the same thing on a "different scale"?

If yes (LOL), that would "explain" why it is not possible to "merge" GR and QM.

Was question like this ever considered?

Comment: The mathematical formulations of GR and QM are completely different. There is no sense in which they are the same theory viewed at different scales. It isn't obvious to me what your quote means. If you can provide a reference I'll have a look at the original to see if I can puzzle it out.

Comment: I think what is meant is that there is only one fundamental theory which should, in principle, cover everything (this is not my opinion, just how I understand the quote). In that sense, GR and QM have to be limits of one thing, i.e. 'the same thing on a "different scale"'.

Comment: Any reason this shouldn't be closed as a duplicate of [A list of inconveniences between quantum mechanics and (general) relativity?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/387/520)