# Has QFT successfully mediated between QM and Special Relativity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity

I understand that [QFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory) is the theoretical framework for combining [QM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics) and [Special Relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity), but as I understand it, though even without proof or experimental confirmations; has QFT managed to "behind all the rigor" design a mathematical construct that fully explains and logically computes there conflicts? Or does it continue to struggle for a formulary solution?

Comment: If you like this question you may also enjoy reading [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/387/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: GammaRay, are you aware of the fact that QFT has a large mass of experimental data supporting its predictions? Think, for instance, of the discovery of the Higgs...

Comment: You are right, I should have made it more clear buy saying something like "though without absolute conclusive proofs".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quantum field theory is a general framework. There are many different kinds of field theories, the most well-known of which are QED (quantum electrodynamics) and QCD (quantum chromodynamics). QED has been shown to agree incredibly well with experiment. The [anomalous magnetic dipole moment of an electron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomalous_magnetic_moment), as computed using QED, agrees with experiment to 10 significant figures, the best agreement between theory and experiment of *any* physical theory in history. The large coupling constant of the strong force makes QCD much more difficult to deal with theoretically, and [confinement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_confinement)  makes it difficult probe experimentally.