# What do quantum theory and general relativity have in common?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, quantum-information, quantum-gravity

What areas of commonality are there between quantum theory and general relativity?

Is it even possible to use the the two when calculating the same physical behaviour?

Is there a correlation between them?

At what point does general relativity fail to work in the world of the atom and why?

Comment: Googling ["constant of Quantum Theory and General Relativity"](https://www.google.dk/#q=%22constant+of+Quantum+Theory+and+General+Relativity%22) returns zero hits. Where have you heard this? There are plenty of endeavors to [reconcile the two theories](https://www.google.dk/#q=reconciling+General+Relativity+and+Quantum+mechanics), but I'm not sure what you mean by a "constant".

Comment: Come on chaps no need for the downvotes, Lorenzo is obviously asking what QM and GR have in common i.e. in what areas are they they same. That's a fair question.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/387/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Funny, just read this feature in Nature:  http://www.nature.com/news/the-quantum-source-of-space-time-1.18797?WT.mc_id=TWT_NatureNews. Brings up some very interesting new things that may have something to do with your question.

Comment: GR or spacetime is essentially classical, there is probably nothing in common. however, you can use dimensional analysis to find the scale both GR and QM are critical.

Comment: Both involve gauge symmetries, albeit 2 completely unrelated ones: if the action is unchanged by a diffeomorphism, one can derive general relativity, with a few principles. Based on the symmetry of action under a particular change of wave function phase, one can derive the standard model of particle physics, explaining electric charge and basically everything we currently know for certain about

Comment: Particles. With a few issues, of course! Internal symmetries are the latter. They change the particles state, not the spatial-temporal state, unlike a diffeomorphism, which is thus called a spacetime symmetry.