# Generalize QFT with gravity by adding metric factor - what's the problem?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, quantum-gravity

[This lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02d00IeKCyQ&index=13&list=PLqOZ6FD_RQ7ln1ZQPEU9aZQsEj0eyGlT6) claims that we can generalize QFT to include gravity by adding a metric-based factor to the integral. This sounds awfully easy. What is actually missing from the approach?

Comment: [As pointed out here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.4748) there is no real problem, except that you have to do real QFT instead of the simplified textbook version of QFT.

Comment: I believe that effective gravitational  quantum field theories are ok if higher order terms can be ignored in the expansion,.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_field_theory#Effective_Field_Theories_in_Gravity  and see section 1.2 here http://cds.cern.ch/record/686730/files/0311082.pdf

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/387/2451 and links therein.