# Is there a classical potential that couldn't be quantized?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gravity, potential, schroedinger-equation

I ask this because I heard that gravity is perhaps not "quantizable" but, on the other hand, schrodinger equation admits potentials like harmonic oscilator and electric (hydrogen atom). So why not do the same with gravity potential?

Comment: Quantum gravity isn’t trying to quantise the Newtonian potential. The naive approach which requires a UV completion is to quantise general relativity in the same manner as a quantum field theory.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/387/2451 and links therein.

Comment: To reopen this question (v1), consider to align title and main body. They seem to ask two different things.

Answer (score 1):

But this is exactly what is done here:
https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0502081

Cold neutrons in quantized states in the (Newtonian) gravitational potential, experimentally measured.