# Can QFT and GR be reconciled in any "not-so-nice" way?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, quantum-gravity

I was talking to a physics professor much more knowledgeable than me the other day, and mentioned "Quantum Gravity", what I've always understood to be a theory that would describe gravity in terms of QM, in contrast to our current understanding of gravity through general relativity.

His response was pretty shocking, along the lines of:

> Well, when you actually work it out, you can get gravity from QM. It's just not in a very nice way.

I didn't get the chance to ask any follow-ups, so my question is: what, specifically, could he have been talking about?

Comment: Seems unlikely to me that anyone will be able to answer this without further clarification from the person who said it. His claim basically sounds false to me, but it's hard to say for sure without knowing what he meant.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/387/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74115/discussion-on-question-by-trefox-can-qft-and-gr-be-reconciled-in-any-not-so-nic).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer by an experimentalist:

It is a well known statement that string theories incorporate quantum gravity and can embed the standard model of physics. [This post](https://motls.blogspot.gr/2014/12/every-theory-of-quantum-gravity-is-part.html) of L.Motl stresses :

> We sometimes say that string theory is the only consistent theory of quantum gravity. It's the only game in town. This is an observation mostly based on various types of circumstantial evidence. Whenever you try something that deviates from string/M-theory, you run into inconsistencies.

.....

> But that doesn't mean that the statement that every consistent theory of quantum gravity has to be nothing else than another approach to string/M-theory is just an expression of vague feelings, a guesswork, or a partial wishful thinking. We don't have the "most complete proof" of this assertion yet – this fact may be partly blamed on the absence of the completely universal, most rigorous definition of both "quantum gravity" and "string theory". But there exist partial proofs and this paper is an example.

referring to the paper under discussion in the post I am quoting.

In the sense that string theories are an extension of Quantum Field Theory, and are not only complicated but also no definitive model has been proposed, which would  predict new phenomena for checking, the statement:

> Well, when you actually work it out, you can get gravity from QM. It's just not in a very nice way

is justified, including my  suspicion that he does not like string theories.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote here, in the current form of the question this was the best answer I could have hoped for. So, string theories may not be experimentally verified but are any actual working theories? Or are there conflicts within string theory we are yet to resolve?

Comment: The problem with string theories is that there are too many/general. They work mathematically , the vibrations of strings can contain the group structure of  the elementary particle standard model, they do have a nich for the expected spin 2 graviton but afaik theorists have not picked one model among the thousand possibilities , to bring forth as a new standard model to be checked and verified or falsified.

Comment: It is far too premature to present a string theory model for experimental testing (and to compare predictions with those of the standard model). we first have to understand what the theory is and this will take more time (than an experimentalist would have hoped) as there are continuously surprises around almost every corner. one problem is that the majority of the string theory community don’t tend to tackle the big and interesting questions (such as what is quantum gravity) because such an approach will not produce many papers and they will end up jobless.