# What equations of general relativity and quantum mechanics are we trying to unify?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, quantum-gravity

In other words, what equations hold the most promise in this endeavour? Are we all looking at the same equations or is this pursuit subjective?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/387/  -- the short version is 1. the problem of how to treat time and 2. the non-renormalizability of Einstein's equations (i.e. canonical quanitzation gives non-renormalizable infinities when applied to Einstein's equations).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A list of inconveniences between quantum mechanics and (general) relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/387/)