# What is the source of the difficulty (within the variational approach framework) in the attempt to unify quantum mechanics with general relativity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, quantum-gravity, variational-principle

It seems to me that quantum mechanics can be formulated within the general mathematical framework of variational  principles.

Derivation of the equations of nonrelativistic quantum mechanics based on the principle of minimum Fisher information.

https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.58.1775

On the other hand, it looks like that is not the case for general relativity.

The Einstein field equations cannot be derived, based on the minimum or maximum of the  action integral.

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00756194

As long ago as 1900, Hilbert formulated problem 23 (In his famous list of problems ).

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_twenty-third_problem

You have to read the original formulation of this problem, not the Wikipedia version. The connection with this question will be clear.

Question 1. Is this the source of the difficulty in the attempt to unify quantum mechanics with general relativity?

Question 2. Is it possible to imagine some other measure of information, related to our knowledge of a physical system  (analogy with Fisher information ),  so that general relativity can be cast within the mathematical framework of variational  principles?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A list of inconveniences between quantum mechanics and (general) relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/387/)

Comment: I read that question  after your comment.  Different perspective.

Comment: To reopen this post (v1) consider to stress the different perspective in main body and especially in title.

Comment: Please edit it as you see fit, if necessary.

Comment: None of the answers to the other question touch the possibly unifying variational  approach.