# As anyone attempted to show that QM and GR cannot be unified?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, quantum-gravity, unified-theories

Sometimes it possible to make very general statement about functional form of things and show, for example, that QM cannot be described by the use of hidden variable (I'm not a physicist in any sense, so excuse imprecision which hopefully aren't gross misunderstanding).

As anyone ever attempted to show that it is impossible to incorporate QM and GR in a single consistent framework?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/387/2451 and links therein.

Comment: It's a misconception that GR and QM cannot be combined in any way. Everything in physics depends on the length scales you probe. At large enough distances, like the distances we probe here on earth, GR+QFT does works just about fine. It's at very short (around Planck length) distances that things get crucially complicated.