# Can Newtonian gravity be quantized?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, quantum-gravity, quantization, galilean-relativity

Today, nobody knows how GR is truly supposed to be married with QFT. As a result, the standard model as it is typically presented does not include gravity. Could it be modified to include Newtonian gravity instead? Although we know that GR is true, the addition of a quantized Newtonian gravity to the standard model would expand the number of scenarios that it could give correct answers for.

Comment: Apparently, linearized gravity *can* be quantized: [Gupta 1952](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0370-1298/65/3/301)

Comment: Newtonian gravity is non-relativistic. However, QFT of the standard model is relativistic. I don't see any reason why QFT could be modified to contain a non-relativistic interaction.

Comment: @LibertarianMonarchistBot That's a good point. You would have to make Newtonian gravity relativistic to fit with QFT, but I would consider that a fair modification.

Comment: but Newtonian gravity by definition is non-relativistic. I guess you want to include the linearized Einstein gravity as S. McGrew pointed out.

Comment: I guess you can also consider non-relativistic QFT instead of QFT of the standard model. For example, the 2nd quantized Schrodinger field theory is such a QFT.

Comment: For the record: Gupta is considering [linearized Einstein gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearized_gravity), not Newtonian gravity.

Answer (score 4):

That's an open problem. Let us here just consider the traditional approach to perturbative (but non-renormalizable) [quantum gravity](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quantum+gravity) (QG). In relativity this approach can be based on the action for [Einstein-Cartan (EC) theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Cartan_theory) by gauging the [Poincare group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_group). To carry out OP's program, we should presumably instead consider an action (if it [exists!](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=newton+cartan+action+principle)) for [Newton-Cartan (NC) theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Cartan_theory) by gauging the [Bargmann group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_transformation#Central_extension_of_the_Galilean_group) (which is a central extension of the [Galilean group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_transformation)). Needless to say that all [the usual problems](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/387/2451) with relativistic QG are only bigger in non-relativistic QG. Good luck!

Comment: Why use Einstein-Cartan action and not the standard Einstein-Hilbert action?

Comment: Because it offers a more general/direct/flexible method to gauge a (not necessarily semisimple) Lie algebra.