# Why graviton theory fails?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, quantum-gravity

What are the different reasons why theory of gravity mediated through gravitons fails?

Comment: Theories of gravity that predict gravitons haven't failed or "succeeded" (whatever that might mean) since they are still hopeful candidates.

Comment: i'm talking about infinities at small distances and such. I read them but couldn't make much sense.

Comment: Which graviton theory are you referring too?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/387/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

A standard QFT for the Einstein action is non-renormalizable, which is problematic. There are other approaches to gravitons, such as string theory, which solves the issue of small-distance divergences by introducing a cutoff-scale: the length of the string.

Comment: can you explain first line more? may be give some citations?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gravity