# Time and the incompatibility of General Relativity and Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, time

Is GR is incompatible with QM because GR has time as an essential dimension whereas QM does not have time?

Is time the key problem to reconciling the two theories?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/387, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/608225

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A list of inconveniences between quantum mechanics and (general) relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/387/37364)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there a “problem of time” in Quantum Gravity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/608225/)