# Reparameterization invariance in gravity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, coordinate-systems, quantum-gravity, ads-cft

It's often said that gravity/general relativity has 'reparameterization invariance.' In particular, this comes up when people talk about the duality between the Sachdev-Ye-Kitaev (SYK) model and Jackiw-Teitelboim gravity, and is apparently key. But I never came across this term when studying general relativity (I worked through Bernard Schutz's 'A First Course in General Relativity' a long time ago).

So, at the level of someone with a semester of GR under their belt, what is reparameterization invariance, and what is its significance in relation to the SYK model?

Comment: See [Why is there a “problem of time” in Quantum Gravity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/608225/) It doesn't discuss the SYK model but it does explain reparameterisation in basic terms.

Comment: Hi user34722: Which reference? Which page?

Comment: Well it's mostly from conversation with people who work in adjacent fields. Subir Sachdev did emphasize it strongly when I saw him give a talk a few years ago (who is a prominent researcher at the interface of High energy physics and condensed matter). For a reference, this review I haven't read yet mentions it on page 15. https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.08482