# How do gravity and the quantum co-exist?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, gravity, unified-theories

In my opinion, the biggest unsolved problem in fundamental physics is how gravity and the quantum will be made to coexist within the same theory. The problem is that quantum physics and general relativity already overlap each other’s domains, but do not fit together. So my question is, how does gravity fit in with the quantum?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Check out the holographic principle.

Comment: By definition a theory is a rational description of observations. There are no observations that require us to describe quantized matter and radiation and gravity at the same time. So in that sense we don't even have a need to propose such a theory. The current scientific overlap between quantum theory and gravitation is, in other words, zero.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [A list of inconveniences between quantum mechanics and (general) relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/387/2451) and links therein.

Comment: You are asking how to solve what you yourself say is the biggest unsolved problem in physics. The key word is *unsolved*, so why are you asking this question?

Answer (score 1):

At present, when there is no definitive theory of quantization of gravity, wherever it is necessary to invoke it, [effective field theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9512024) gravitational quantization models are used.

In general, whenever  there is a singularity in classical physics theories, the mainstream physics posits a quantum field  theory where the probability nature of quantum mechanics makes the singularity mathematically viable.

For many physics problems effective QFT's exist, where "effective" means that the [renormalization scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization) does not work, but within observational and experimental limits the theory is useful. An example exists in the cosmological [Big Bang  model w](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang)here effective quantization of gravity reduces the singularity to a locus.  The BB model is consistent with observations using this hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

They did indeed coexist as coequals in the very early universe. The real problem is that no one yet knows how to write down a mathematical model that successfully describes that coexistence.