# Why is gravity not quantum?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, quantum-gravity

My main question is about brief information about gravity. For example, why is gravity not quantum?
What is the main problem with gravity? Why is gravity the weakest force?
Of course, from the perspective of researchers who firmly believe in this theory. Not those who do not consider gravity as a fundamental force.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A list of inconveniences between quantum mechanics and (general) relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/387/)

Comment: There is a very large body of study on how gravity might be quantum.   A few months ago I attended the "Quantum Gravity Institute" symposium in Vancouver.  It was attended by many leading physicists, including several Nobel Lauriets.   You can see the abstracts here: https://conference.quantumgravityinstitute.ca/abstracts/     Choose your favourite and delve deeper.

Comment: Most physicists assume that gravity *must* be quantized. They just aren’t sure yet about how to do that properly.

Comment: @foolishmuse Which one of them is your favourite?

Comment: @KP99  I'm a big proponent of Loop Quantum Gravity, as put forth by Abhay Ashtekar and others.  You can find my highly speculative concept of gravity based on LQG here: https://vixra.org/abs/2202.0156

Comment: @foolishmuse Interesting! I am fond of Twistor theory , but not as a theory of quantum gravity, rather I see it as a mathematical tool which can set the foundation for correct QG theory.